# Printing array of integers generates weird output in Ada

Tags: arrays, gcc, int, ada

I created a simple Ada program that allows a user to populate an array with a maximum of 100 non negative and non zero integers and then prints them out. When I call the function to print out the numbers it prints them out but at the same time it also prints out a bunch of strange and seemingly random numbers. What mistake have I made in my code that is causing the program to output such strange  results? This is my first time writing in Ada. For example when I populate the empty array with the numbers [1,2,3,4,5] is prints out this:

```
    1
          2
          3
          4
          5
      32624
  911328835
      32624
  911328836
      32624
   67043328
  134217726
  134217726
 2013265921
  134217726
  134217726
  134217726
   67043328
  909181968
      32624
 2114692683
      89452
  914381552
      32624
 1543503876
          2
         14
          2
         14
```

I am using the gnatmake compiler on ubuntu and when compiling the source code it doesn't give me any error/warning messages.

Here is my source code, I know that I probably don't need to use seperate functions but I implemented them anyways for learning purposes.

```
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Containers;


procedure thing is 
type Vector is array (1..100) of Integer;
A: Vector;--array doesn't need to be completely filled up

K: Integer;
--array filling function below
function mkarr return Vector is --asks user to fill empty array with positive and non zero integers

begin

Ada.Text_IO.Put ("enter numbers to fill array, negative or 0 will stop process: ");
for I in 1..100 loop
    Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(K);
    if K>0 then
        A(I) := K;
    end if;
    if K<=0 then
        return A;
    end if;

end loop;
return A;
end;




--array printing prodcedure below
procedure printarr(A: in out Vector) is
begin
    for I in A'Range loop
    if A(I)>0 then
        Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(A(I));
        New_Line(1);
    end if;
    end loop;
end printarr;



B: Vector := mkarr;


--main method below
begin



printarr(A);
end thing;
```

Comment: Quick fix : `A: Vector := (others => 0);` Then do some reading to understand how and why it works. Better : make 'mkarr' return the correct size vector (which is easy and doesn't need `Ada.Containers`.

Answer (score 6):

In `mkarr`, you use a 0 or negative value to mark the end of the input, but you don't store that value in the array. If whatever garbage is stored in the array after the end of the values you entered happens to be positive, there's no way to tell that it's not a valid value.

In `printarr`, if you encounter a 0 or negative value you don't print it -- but you continue printing the remaining positive values (which are garbage).

If you store a sentinel value in `mkarr`, and quit printing in `printarr` when you encounter the sentinel, the program should work.

Some other notes:

`A` and `K` are used only inside `mkarr`. They should be local to `mkarr`.

You never use `Ada.Containers.Vectors`. You can delete the corresponding `with` and `use` directives.

For more advanced usage, you can have `mkarr` return an array containing only the entered data, by making `Vector` an unconstrained array type and returning a slice. It's still easier to define a fixed-length array inside `mkarr`. Allowing arbitrarily many inputs is tricker -- but `Ada.Containers` is probably a good way to do that. (Disclaimer: I haven't looked at `Ada.Containers`.)

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [Keith’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61568715/40851):
You want a variable-length result, so the more Ada-like way is to use an "unconstrained array":

```ada
type Vector is array (Positive range <>) of Integer;
```

This means that you can create instances of the array of any size you like, so long as the bounds are positive: 1 .. 100, 42 .. 43 etc. You can even create a zero-length array by specifying the last bound (called `’Last`) to be less than the first (called `’First`). In this special circumstance, you’re allowed to use a `’Last` outside the range of the index type (in this case, 0, or even -42 if you want to confuse people!).

```ada
function mkarr return Vector is
```

We have to have an actual array to accumulate the values, so set an upper limit of 100.

```ada
   Result : Vector (1 .. 100);
```

We need to know how many elements there are.

```
   Last : Natural := Result'First - 1;
```

More or less as before,

```ada
   K : Integer;
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put
     ("enter numbers to fill array, negative or 0 will stop process: ");
   for I in Result'Range loop
```

We can return an array with at most `Result’Length` elements.

```ada
      Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get (K);
      if K > 0 then
```

We can add one more element.

```ada
         Last := Last + 1;
         Result (Last) := K;
      else
```

There are fewer than 100 elements, so return just that slice.

```
         return Result (Result'First .. Last);
      end if;
   end loop;
```

We’ve accumulated 100 results, so return all of them.

```ada
   return Result;
end mkarr;
```

Comment: To make things more Ada-like, one would have the components of the array be of subtype `Positive` and rename `Count` to `Last` of subtype `Natural`, since in the general case it's the last index used, which might be different from a Count of values added.

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter, good points; I’ve adopted the `Last` one, but left the components of the array as `Integer` because that was OP’s choice

Answer (score 1):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61568715/230513), your example mentions [`Ada.Containers.Vectors`](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html) with no further reference to the package. If you pursue such a solution, discussed [here](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-8-2.html), you might first instantiate the generic package `Vectors` to get a resizable container of integers:

```
package Integer_Container is new Vectors (Natural, Integer);
```

Your function to make an array can then declare a `Vector` named `A` and initialize its elements and length to specific values:

```
function Make_Array (Size : Count_Type) return Vector is
A : Vector := To_Vector (New_Item => -1, Length => Size);
…
```

You can use [*Iteration*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-6-3.html) in Ada 2012 to simplify your data collection in `Make_Array`:

```
for E of A loop
   Get (K);
   if K > 0 then
      E := K;
   else
      exit;
   end if;
end loop;
```

Similarly, a `procedure Print_Array (A : in Vector)` might loop like this:

```
for E of A loop
   Put (E, 4);
end loop;
```

A typical usage might look something like this:

```
Print_Array (Make_Array (42));
```

Additional details may be found [here](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/standard_library.html#containers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bada%5D%20Ada.Containers.Vectors).