# Passing an array to a function in Ada

Tags: ada

I am trying to pass my array of integers called "Arr" to a function "collect". inside of collect, I am collecting an int from the user. once the user puts in 100 ints or gives a value of 0 or a negative number the array will stop collecting. What am I doing wrong?

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure helloworld is

   procedure PrintHelloWorld is
   begin
      Put_Line ("Enter Integers, up to 100 individual ints.");
   end PrintHelloWorld;

   function collect (A : array) return array is

      A: array (1 .. 100) of integer;

   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put ("Enter an integer: ");
      Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(I);
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Integer'Image(I));   
      if I > 0 then
         A(i) := I;
      end if;
   while I > 0 loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Put ("Enter an integer: ");
      Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(I);
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Integer'Image(I));   
      if I > 0 then
         A(i) := I;
      end if;
   end loop;
      return A;
   end collect;
   procedure printArr is
   begin
      for j in Arr'range loop
         Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Integer'Image(Arr(j)));
      end loop;
   end printArr;
   Arr: array (1 .. 100) of integer;
   Arr := (others => 0);
   I: Integer;
begin

   Put_Line ("Hello World!");
   PrintHelloWorld;
   Arr := collect(Arr);
   printArr;
end helloworld;
```

Terminal errors:

```
gnatmake helloworld.adb
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-8 -c helloworld.adb
helloworld.adb:13:26: anonymous array definition not allowed here
helloworld.adb:13:46: reserved word "is" cannot be used as identifier
helloworld.adb:15:08: missing ")"
gnatmake: "helloworld.adb" compilation error
```

Comment: You are probably getting messages from the compiler that the function doesn't return anything. Well, it doesn't.  Furthermore you have a global variable, a formal parameter to the function, and a local variable, all with the same name. Guess which one is visible... Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61568595/printing-array-of-ints-generates-weird-output-in-ada : presumably one of your classmates working on the same assignment?

Comment: `function collect (A : array) return array` won’t even compile. You need to declare an array type.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank you for the response. I updated my code along with the errors from the terminal.

Comment: @SimonWright so would something like this be an array type? 
type Vector is array (Integer range <>) of Integer;

Comment: 1) If you're passing an array IN to `collect` : make it a procedure with an `In Out` mode parameter, (No need for two arrays : simpler.) 2) Also : initialise the array in its declaration, e.g. by `:= (others => 0)` so it doesn't contain garbage. 3) Don't use magic numbers when looping over the array (you have beautifully illustrated why!) : use `for i in Arr'range` instead.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I am looking online for some resources on what a procedure with In Out mode parameter is and can't seem to find anything. Could you give me an example? Thank you for your help. Also I updated the code with your recommendations!

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming specifically https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Subprograms
Also the initialiser is part of the declaration : `Arr: array (1 .. 100) of integer := (others => 0);`

Answer (score 4):

It appears that your thinking is stuck somewhere between C/C++/Java syntax and Ada. Try the following example.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type Data_Array is array(Positive range <>) of Integer;

   function Collect return Data_Array is
      Count : Natural := 0;
   begin
      Put_Line("Enter the number of data values you will input");
      Get(Count);
      declare
         Nums : Data_Array(1..Count);
      begin
         Put_Line("Enter" & Count'Image &" values");
         for Value of Nums loop
            Get(Value);
         end loop;
         return Nums;
      end;
   end Collect;

   procedure Print(Item : in Data_Array) is
   begin
      Put_Line("Output of array values:");
      for Value of Item loop
         Put_Line(Value'Image);
      end loop;
   end Print;

begin
   Print(Collect);
end Main;
```

The procedure Print takes a parameter of type Data_Array, which is provided by the return value of the function Collect.
The function collect only returns an array of exactly the size needed. The procedure Print takes an array of whatever size you send it and prints the contents of that array.

Comment: The definition of the array inside of function collect (in the original code) may come from the Fortran 77 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are; I've also made it so you can add negative numbers.
(If that's not what you want, change the element type of Vector to `Natural` or `Positive` as desired.)
Note that the `--'` comments are a workaround to the buggy syntax highlighter.

```ada
Pragma Ada_2012;
Pragma Assertion_Policy( Ignore );
Pragma Restrictions( No_Implementation_Aspect_Specifications );
Pragma Restrictions( No_Implementation_Pragmas               );

With
Ada.Strings.Equal_Case_Insensitive,
Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams;

Procedure Example is

   -- Counting and indexing types.
   Type Count is range 0..100;
   Subtype Index is Count range Count'Succ(Count'First)..Count'Last; --'

   -- Array-type; its range is constrained by Index.
   Type Vector is Array(Index range <>) of Integer;

   -- Here we build the input-vector.
   Function Get_Input return Vector is

      -- Here we get user-input; we pass our working-set as a parameter so
      -- that it can be built in-place; this also ensures that we only ever
      -- generate a result of the appropriate length.
      Function Get_Working( Working : Vector:= (2..1 => <>) ) return Vector is
         Function "="(Left, Right : String) Return Boolean
           renames Ada.Strings.Equal_Case_Insensitive;
      Begin
         -- We never try to add to a full array.
         if Working'Length = Index'Last then
           return Working;
         end if;
         -- We get an integer, or are finished.
         loop
            Ada.Text_IO.Put( "Enter an integer or type 'Done': " );
            READ_INPUT:
            Declare
               User_Input  : Constant String:= Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line;
            Begin
               return Get_Working( Working & Integer'Value(User_Input) ); --'
            Exception
               when Constraint_Error =>
                  if User_Input = "Done" then
                     return Working;
                  end if;
            End READ_INPUT;         
         end loop;     
      End Get_Working;
   Begin
      Return Get_Working;
   End Get_Input;

   Procedure Print( Object : Vector ) is
   Begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put( '[' );
      for Index in Object'Range loop --'
         Ada.Text_IO.Put( Integer'Image(Object(Index)) ); --'
         if Index /= Object'Last then --'
            Ada.Text_IO.Put(',');
         end if;
      end loop;
      Ada.Text_IO.Put( ']' );
   End Print;



Begin
   declare
      V : constant Vector:= Get_Input;
   begin
      Print( V );
      Ada.Text_IO.New_Line( 2 );
   end;

   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line( "Done." );
End Example;
```

Example run:
`Enter an integer or type 'Done': 21`
`Enter an integer or type 'Done': 4`
`Enter an integer or type 'Done': 18`
`Enter an integer or type 'Done': DONE`
`[ 21, 4, 18]`

`Done.`